# How to invert long term to short term using ACRONYM list?

Tags: acronyms

In my text, I'd like to have in first use of `\ac` the result (all my text is typed using `\ac` or `\acp`):

> PC (Personal Computer)

So, normally the result is opposite:

> Personal Computer (PC)

How to customize it?

Answer (score 4):

Change the definition of the macros `\acfa` and `\@acf` (EDIT: and their plural couterparts).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acronym}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\acfa}[1]{%
%    \texorpdfstring{\protect\@acf{#1}}{\AC@acl{#1} (#1)}}% DELETED
   \texorpdfstring{\protect\@acf{#1}}{#1\ (\AC@acl{#1})}}% NEW
\renewcommand*{\@acf}[1]{%
    \ifAC@footnote
       \acsfont{\AC@acs{#1}}%
       \footnote{\AC@placelabel{#1}\AC@acl{#1}{}}%
    \else
       \acffont{%
%           \AC@placelabel{#1}\AC@acl{#1}% DELETED
          \AC@placelabel{#1}\AC@acs{#1}% NEW
          \nolinebreak[3] %
%           \acfsfont{(\acsfont{\AC@acs{#1}})}% DELETED
          \acfsfont{(\acsfont{\AC@acl{#1}})}% NEW
        }%
     \fi
     \ifAC@starred\else\AC@logged{#1}\fi}
\renewcommand*{\acfpa}[1]{%
   \texorpdfstring{\protect\@acfp{#1}}{\AC@acsp{#1} (\AC@aclp{#1})}}
\renewcommand*{\@acfp}[1]{%
   \ifAC@footnote
      \acsfont{\AC@acsp{#1}}%
      \footnote{\AC@placelabel{#1}\AC@aclp{#1}{}}%
   \else
      \acffont{%
         \AC@placelabel{#1}\AC@acsp{#1}%
         \nolinebreak[3] %
         \acfsfont{(\acsfont{\AC@aclp{#1}})}%
         }%
   \fi
   \ifAC@starred\else\AC@logged{#1}\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text about the \ac{PC}~\dots

More about the \ac{PC}~\dots

\begin{acronym}
\acro{PC}{Personal Computer}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't find a better solution declare a new command combining short and long forms, something like (not tested)

```
\newcommand{\firstac}[1]{\acl{#1} (\acs{#1})}
```