# How to change text generated in package acronym

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to invert long term to short term using ACRONYM list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20917/how-to-invert-long-term-to-short-term-using-acronym-list)

This is a newbie question, how to change the text generated by `\ac` command, like:

I have this:

```
\usepackage[nolist,nohyperlinks]{acronym}
%...

\acrodef{CBR}{\emph{Content-Based Retrieval}}
```

When I use `\ac{CBR}` I have this:

> Content-Based Retrieval (CBR)

but I need this

> Content-Based Retrieval -- CBR

or this:

> CBR -- Content-Based Retrieval

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question appears to be a duplicate of the question linked to by Ignasi; closing duplicate questions is needed to keep the site as informative as possible. Please, have a look at that question and, if you are not able to adapt it to your needs, tell here why.